# Custom Json response from web api

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am working on ASP .Net web api project where we are giving response of a custom object. JsonFormatter formats the data to a json object when api is exposed in fiddler. Here is the skeleton of our application.

**Data Objects**

```
public class CustomData
{
  public Records MRecord {get;set;}
  public string ResponseCode {get;set;}
  public string Status {get;set;}
}

public class Records
{
  Public class FirstName {get;set;}
  Public class LastName {get;set;}
}
```

**Response**

```
CustomData : {
  MRecord : [
   {
     FirstName : "1stName",
     LastName : "",
   },
   {
     FirstName : "2Name",
     LastName : "",
   },
 ],
 ResponseCode : "0",
 Status: "Success"
}
```

And the **expected format** is like

```
CustomData : {
    MRRecordList : {
      MRecord : 
       {
         FirstName : "1stName",
         LastName : "",
       },
      MRecord :
       {
         FirstName : "2Name",
         LastName : "",
       }
     },
     ResponseCode : "0",
     Status: "Success"
    }
```

Considering the array objects aren't split and shown as a single entity by the JsonFormatter. Please help me if there is any solution to achieve this.

Comment: Isn't your expected response invalid? The MRRecordList has multiple properties with the same name.

Comment: In addition to @YuriyFaktorovich comment that your object model is invalid, even the Json is invalid, Json doesn't have a tag / name for root object

Comment: "any solution to achieve this"  Achieve what? I don't know what you're asking.

Comment: you should talk to those with the service so they accept the valid Json, but else replace [] with {} and Bob is your uncle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the code / model you need:

```
void Main()
{
    var c = new CustomData()
    {
        MRecordList = new List<UserQuery.Record>
        {
          new Record{FirstName="A",LastName="B"},
          new Record{FirstName="C",LastName="D"}
        },
        ResponseCode = "0",
        Status = ""     
    };

    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c).Dump();
}


public class CustomData
{
    public List<Record> MRecordList { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    public string FirstName { get;set;}     
    public string LastName { get;set;}
}
```

This will yield the following Json:

```
{
    "MRecordList": [{
        "FirstName": "A",
        "LastName": "B"
    }, {
        "FirstName": "C",
        "LastName": "D"
    }],
    "ResponseCode": "0",
    "Status": ""
}
```

In case your requirement is the following Json:

```
{
    "customData": {
        "MRecordList": [{
            "FirstName": "A",
            "LastName": "B"
        }, {
            "FirstName": "C",
            "LastName": "D"
        }],
        "ResponseCode": "0",
        "Status": ""
    }
}
```

then make following changes to the code:

```
public class Test
{
    public CustomData customData {get;set;}
}

Test t = new Test{customData = c};

Now serialize t
```

Remember no root tag in Json as clear from the above examples

Comment: My bad, I haven't mentioned  "List<Record>" object in the question. I am able to achieve the response as you have shown. I want the response like,

    MRecord : 
       {
         FirstName : "1stName",
         LastName : "",
       },
      MRecord :
       {
         FirstName : "2Name",
         LastName : "",
           }

Is that possible to have json data with property name ?

Comment: That is not a valid Json, you can at most make it `Dictionary<string,Record>`, which will mark the elements with string name identifier, but even then each identifier needs to be different, it cannot be "MRecord", it shall be "MRecord0", "MRecord1", so on and so forth

Comment: What ever you might consider, first validate, whether json is valid or not, then comes formatting in the correct format, use the [Json Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) validator

Comment: Thanks Mrinal. Yes I understand, its not a valid json format as property can't repeat. I will stick to my existing json. Thanks for your help.